# getting Stale element exception in katalon while selecting checkbox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

Can any one help me with same exception as i am getting this exception 2 out of 5 times while running my code

```
public selectTags(int tags){
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    for(int i=1; i<=tags; i++){
        WebElement elementCheckBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.v-scrollable.v-table-body-wrapper.v-table-body div:nth-child(1) table tbody tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child(1) input'))
        if(!elementCheckBox.isSelected()){
            elementCheckBox.click()
            WebUI.delay(1)
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML CODE:**
[image]
It would be very helpful if some one can help on this?

Comment: Please add exception or error that you are facing.

Comment: Your css selector seems very fragile. Please share the HTML around the element you are trying to click.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you share HTML elements?
It might help to solve problem.

and I think you should use delay before if and before click

```
 for(int i=1; i<=tags; i++){
    WebElement elementCheckBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.v-scrollable.v-table-body-wrapper.v-table-body div:nth-child(1) table tbody tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child(1) input'))
    WebUI.delay(1)
    if(!elementCheckBox.isSelected()){
        WebUI.delay(1)
        elementCheckBox.click()
        WebUI.delay(1)
    }
}
```